# how can i get milliseconds with a date

Tags: datetime

i am trying this

```
Datetime t=Convert.ToDateTime(row["TimeStamp"])
```

i am getting this record from Database dat contains the milliseconds too
but when i do this i lose the milliseconds
how can i get the milliseconds

Comment: Which database as well?  It might be a precision problem on that side.

Comment: You're very modest. If I had a date, I'd want to spend at least an evening with her.

Comment: Looks like .NET generally http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todatetime.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From [this MSDN article on ToDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todatetime.aspx) it looks like either a string or an object is being passed in. Either way, the method returns a [DateTime object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_members.aspx), which has properties Millisecond, Second etc. So, I suggest you try:

```
t.Millisecond
```

If its value is 0 then check that there are milliseconds in the original string, not just seconds.